# Set a static string if field is not empty [ASPNET MVC]

Tags: viewbag, redirecttoaction, asp-net-mvc-1

I have this problem:

I have a result grid with a column named **Note**. I want to set a static string into the column cell (e.g: **Nota**) if note field is full (now in this field there is the note content) else I want to display a empty cell.

This is my Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(CLI_POLIZZA cli_polizza)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cliPolizzaManager = new CliPolizzaManager(); 

            cli_polizza.RegistrazioneID = Guid.NewGuid();

            if (cli_polizza.Tipo =="C"){

            cliPolizzaManager.GetScadenza(dataScadenza, 
            cli_polizza.GGAnticipo);
               var dataScadenza = (DateTime)cli_polizza.DataScad;
                cli_polizza.DataAvviso = dataScadenza.AddDays((-1) * (double)cli_polizza.GGAnticipo);
            }

            db.CLI_POLIZZA.Add(cli_polizza);
            db.SaveChanges();
            **if (cli_polizza.Nota != null)
            {
                TempData["Message"] = "Nota";
            }**
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }



        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var cli_polizza = db.CLI_POLIZZA.Include(c => c.CLIENTE).Include(c => c.POLIZZA);
        ViewBag.Message = TempData["Message"];
        return View(cli_polizza.ToList());
    }
```

This is my View:

```
 <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CLIENTE.FullName)
            </td>
            ...
            <td>
                 **@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => @ViewBag.Message)**
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-sm">@Html.ActionLink("Modifica", "Edit", new { id = item.RegistrazioneID }) </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">@Html.ActionLink("Dettaglio", "Details", new { id = item.RegistrazioneID })  </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">@Html.ActionLink("Cancella", "Delete", new { id = item.RegistrazioneID }) </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

I can't use viewbag with redirecttoaction so I tried to use Tempdata but with No result: I'm newbie

I would like to have following result:

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Model.Note==null? “Note”: Model.Note
```

Comment: With your statement VS returns me this error:
Error 1 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PolizzeManager.Models.CLI_POLIZZA>' does not contain a definition for 'Nota' and no extension method 'Nota' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<PolizzeManager.Models.CLI_POLIZZA>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 

If I use item.Nota (instead of Model.Nota) project builds but in my Note column I see " ==null ? “Note”: Model.Note" instead of "Nota" or blanc